# octave fminunc alternate in perl/pdl

Tags: perl, octave, gradient-descent

Is there an alternative to the [`fminunc`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) function (from octave/matlab) in perl?

I want to run gradient descent to get minimum value of theta something like octave `fminunc`:

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 200);
[theta, cost] = ...
    fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t,X,y)), initial_theta, options);
```

what is the Perl way to do this ?

Comment: See also [Algorithm::LBFGS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::LBFGS)